# Regex to match a pattern in a given text

Tags: regex

Given Sample Text -

> This is just testing user1 (Dreamer: db-vd) test test user 2
> (company1) (Super: ab-cd1): user_lore set from 'Sc' to 'Re', Ext PID
> hit from '' to 'tom.hanks1@tt.com', Make O profiles disabled, Make A
> Groups enabled, Shift P configurations enabled, A groups set from
> 'abc' to 'abc'

Pattern to find in the above text -

```
Ext PID hit from '' to 'tom.hanks1@tt.com'
```

Need to take care that `tom.hanks1` before @ is a variable and could be anything like `brad_pitt2` or `abc.abc123`

If the regex pattern is present in the text then I need to do something. What I came up with is given below:

```
/Ext PID hit from \'\' to \'.*@tt\.com\'/
```

Doesn't look effective so need help with the regex to be used! Appreciate it.

Comment: Your pattern seems to work. You might write it like this to match at least 1 non whitespace character other than an `@` char `\bExt PID hit from '' to '[^\s@]+@tt\.com'` https://regex101.com/r/SsFRyU/1

Comment: Yours is working: https://regex101.com/r/h5rWhu/1  maybe you've got something like case sensitive on?